# How do I check to which row area field a cell in a pivottable belongs to?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable in compact form layout (default layout) with multiple row area fields. This results in multiple grouping levels with buttons to collapse or expand rows.

I want to modify a cell depending on the grouping level the row is in.

How can I check in which row the cell is in?

The only idea I had so far was to check the value of the leftmost cell in the corresponding row and compare it with each item from each rowField.

But I guess there is a smarter way?

Comment: Frank...can you post a link to a screenshot that illustrates what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, it took me a while but at the end it was super easy.
PivotCell.RowItems.Count was the information I needed. Depending on the count I wanted to manipulate the cell.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while. But at the end I just needed PivotCell.RowItems.Count

Depending on the Count result I can new manipulate the cell.